# Java hexBinary needs to be even-length

Tags: java, aes

Basically the file contains 16 bytes of text but when its more than 16 bytes it throws out the error:
hexBinary needs to be even-length.

Error at:

```
byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(content));
```

Do I need to use other cipher methods or padding?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  convertToHex(System.out, new File("E:\\TESTS\\kristersss.txt"));
  //write the output into a file
  convertToHex(new PrintStream("E:\\TESTS\\kristersssHex.txt"), new File("E:\\TESTS\\kristersss.txt"));

  System.out.println( "  " ); 
  System.out.println( "128-bit hex key example: ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff" );
  String content = new Scanner(new File("E:\\TESTS\\kristersssHex.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
  System.out.println("----------FAILA SATURS----------");


  System.out.println(content);

  System.out.println("------------------------------");    
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );

  System.out.println( "Enter 128-bit hex key: " );
  final String keyHex = scanner.nextLine();

  final String plaintextHex = "aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccff";
  SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(DatatypeConverter
      .parseHexBinary(keyHex), "AES");

  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

  byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter
      .parseHexBinary(content));

  String a = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(result);
  System.out.println("----------FAILA SATURA ENKRIPTACIJA----------");
  System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(result));
  BufferedWriter output = null;
  try {

    File file = new File("E:\\TESTS\\kristerssEncrypts.txt");
    output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    output.write(a);
  } catch ( IOException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    if ( output != null ) {
      output.close();
    }
  }

  Cipher cipherd = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
  cipherd.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

  byte[] result2 = cipherd.doFinal(result);
  System.out.println("----------FAILA SATURA DEKRIPTACIJA----------");
  System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(result2));
  BufferedWriter outputt = null;
  String aa = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(result2);
  try {

    File file = new File("E:\\TESTS\\kristerssDekrypts.txt");
    outputt = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    outputt.write(aa);
  } catch ( IOException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    if ( outputt != null ) {
      outputt.close();
    }
  }
```

Class that converts file string to hex.

```
public static void convertToHex(PrintStream out, File file) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        int bytesCounter =0;
        int value = 0;
        StringBuilder sbHex = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();

        while ((value = is.read()) != -1) {
            //convert to hex value with "X" formatter
                sbHex.append(String.format("%02X", value));

            //If the chracater is not convertable, just print a dot symbol "."
            if (!Character.isISOControl(value)) {
                sbText.append((char)value);
            }else {
                sbText.append(".");
            }

            //if 16 bytes are read, reset the counter,
                //clear the StringBuilder for formatting purpose only.
            if(bytesCounter==15){
                sbResult.append(sbHex).append("");
                sbHex.setLength(0);
                sbText.setLength(0);
                bytesCounter=0;
            }else{
                bytesCounter++;
            }
           }

        //if still got content
        if(bytesCounter!=0){
             //add spaces more formatting purpose only
            for(; bytesCounter<16; bytesCounter++){
            //1 character 3 spaces
            sbHex.append("   ");
            }
            sbResult.append(sbHex).append("");
            }

            out.print(sbResult);
            is.close();
      }
```

What I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Take file that contains text.
2. Convert text to hex.
3. Convert hex to binaryhex.
4. Encrypt the file content.
5. Write to new file.
6. Decrypt the new hex content.
7. Write to new file.

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to do, first.. And why are you converting to hex and then back?

Comment: «Do i need to use other cipher methods or padding?» — It depends on what you would like to accomplish.

Comment: Well at the moment i'm trying to understand why my file can't be bigget than 16 bytes. @SergeyBrunov

Comment: @xs0 Edited first post, what i'm tryin to accomplish

Comment: @humbleman, the file size can be greater, but it must be a multiple of the block size (128 bits): [Advanced Encryption Standard - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no need to convert to "hex" and to "binaryhex".. Use Files.readAllBytes() to get the contents and encrypt that..